# Is SPA a monolith in the browser?

Tags: reactjs, angular, single-page-application

When I publish my SPA, I am deploying the entire code base. Are we entering an age in which we can say that what today is fancy SPA would tomorrow be a monolith in the browser?

Comment: Yes/No/Maybe/It Depends. What does `Monolith` even mean? Are mobile applications monoliths for example? While the original term in the 1990s meant any system or design that tried to do everything in a single module/system/whatsit, the term is now used as a bogey man to disparage older technologies and promote a new one. Which usually just moves the complexity to another point.

Comment: Most SPA's are a front end calling a bunch of web services. That doesn't sound monolithic to me. Especially if it's split into the usual things like HTML, javascript, CSS etc.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree that the term is used as a bogey man these days. I am not using it as a bogey man, though.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Even monoliths made network requests to database, so monoliths are  simpler distributed systems. Nothing wrong with that. And there is sub division in monoliths that is modularized.

Comment: @Rajat my point is that the question has no meaning. What do you even mean `monolith` and why do you care? Something is a monolith only if it's too big for the job and tries to do too much, where `too much` depends entirely on the current application. Again, is a mobile application a monolith? How can it be if most of the job is done by a server talking to a database? But what if you want to create a *composite* application, combining multiple other modules/applications ? You need a composite UI for that. And how do you deploy the components?

Comment: @Rajat btw the composite UI I described was *very* fashionable in 2008 for desktop applications, especially in big organizations that wanted to combine different apps that had nothing in common. It was also very common in the late 1990s/early 2000s when the first intranet portals were created. Using multiple IFRAMEs on a page may be outdated but its far more decoupled than any JavaScript microfrontend framework

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the size and scope of your SPA. Does your SPA handle a single business domain / piece of functionality? Then maybe it isn't a monolith. Consider how Microsoft describes microservices:

> - Microservices are small, independent, and loosely coupled. A single small team of developers can write and maintain a service.
> - Each service is a separate codebase, which can be managed by a small development team.
> - Services can be deployed independently. A team can update an existing service without rebuilding and redeploying the entire application.
> - Services are responsible for persisting their own data or external state. This differs from the traditional model, where a separate data layer handles data persistence.
> - Services communicate with each other by using well-defined APIs. Internal implementation details of each service are hidden from other services.
> - Services don't need to share the same technology stack, libraries, or frameworks.
>
> -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/architecture-styles/microservices#what-are-microservices

Contrast those points against your SPA. If you find your SPA bundles a large variety of functionality that cross multiple business domains, then look at how you could split that functionality out. What can be deployed independently?

> The term Micro Frontends first came up in ThoughtWorks Technology Radar at the end of 2016. It extends the concepts of micro services to the frontend world. The current trend is to build a feature-rich and powerful browser application, aka single page app, which sits on top of a micro service architecture. Over time the frontend layer, often developed by a separate team, grows and gets more difficult to maintain. That’s what we call a Frontend Monolith.
>
> -- https://micro-frontends.org/

Can functionality be shrunk down to a single sharable component? Then maybe you'd want to consider a micro-frontend pattern.
https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html
https://micro-frontends.org/